# Odoo- When convert opportunity or lead to customer . the custom fields and data not mapping or not populating on customers

Tags: odoo

Like I have created the "School Name" field on Opportunity or lead Form. the same field on customers form. When converting from Lead to Customers how to convert the customer data field data from Lead to customers
please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a community around programming, coding. Please show a [mre] so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't enough to just add fields with same name to both models. When you confirm your lead to partner-object (no such object in Odoo as customer), you call a method. You need to overwrite that method and add functionality there to copy your field content to new object.